# How to plot the GLSL expression

Tags: plotting, graphics

What's the most compact WL translation of this GLSL expression:

```
length(max(vec2(x,y),0))
```

?

My best attempt (using Wolfram Development Platform, not Mathematica) is

```
EuclideanDistance [{0,0},{Max[x,0],Max[y,0]}]
```

which works

[image]

but repeats Max.

This

```
EuclideanDistance [{0,0},Max[{x,y},0]]
```

fails thus:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Ramp](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ramp.html)

```
Norm @ Ramp @ {x,y}
```

> Sqrt[Abs[Ramp[x]]^2 + Abs[Ramp[y]]^2]

```
Simplify[Ramp[x] - Max[x, 0]]
```

> 0

```
 Plot3D[Norm[Ramp@{x,y}],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]
```

[image]

### [UnitStep](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitStep.html)

```
Norm[{x, y} UnitStep[{x, y}]]
```

> Sqrt[Abs[x UnitStep[x]]^2 + Abs[y UnitStep[y]]^2]

```
Simplify[x UnitStep[x] - Max[x, 0]]
```

> 0

Comment: Great. Thanks. Here's another Q: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163598/translation-of-glsl-expression-2

Answer (score 1):

I would just write it out

```
Sqrt[Max[0, x]^2 + Max[0, y]^2]
```

To me, this is clearer than the alternatives which include your version maybe these two

```
Sqrt[#.#] &[Max[0, #] & /@ {x, y}]
EuclideanDistance[{0, 0}, Max[0, #] & /@ {x, y}]
```