# Translation of GLSL expression (2)

Tags: expression-construction

What's the most compact WL translation of this [`GLSL`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language) expression:

length(max(vec2(x,y),s))

?

Comment: What does it do? What are x, y, s?

Comment: If you have to ask, you won't know the answer. If you want to find out, learn GLSL.

Comment: @ChrisJJ It is not how it works, this site is about Wolfram Mathematica, everything that does not concern it should be explained in the question, making it clear and useful for future visitors.

Comment: Additionaly, I don't understand your repost, don't existing answers solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Norm[s + Ramp[{x, y} - s]]
```

> Sqrt[Abs[s + Ramp[-s + x]]^2 + Abs[s + Ramp[-s + y]]^2]

```
ClearAll[x, y, s]
Reduce[s + Ramp[{x,y} - s] == {Max[x, s], Max[y, s]}, {x, y, s}, Reals]
```

> True

```
Manipulate[Row[{Plot3D[Norm[s + Ramp[{x, y} - s]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, Exclusions -> None], 
  Plot3D[Norm[Max[#, s] & /@ {x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> 400]}], 
 {s, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Norm[s + ({x,y} - s) UnitStep[{x,y} -s]]
```

> Sqrt[Abs[s + (-s + x) UnitStep[-s + x]]^2 + Abs[s + (-s + y) UnitStep[-s + y]]^2]

```
Reduce[s + ({x,y}-s) UnitStep[{x, y} - s] == {Max[x, s], Max[y, s]}, {x,y, s}, Reals]
```

> True